# How Do I Restrict Repository Access via WebSVN?

Tags: svn, apache, access-control, websvn

Note: I originally asked this question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/13853/how-do-i-restrict-repository-access-via-websvn) but only got one response so far, and the more I think about it, the more I realise it is probably better on stackoverflow.

I have multiple subversion repositories which are served up through Apache 2.2 and WebDAV. They are all located in a central place, and I used this [debian-administration.org](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/208) article as the basis (I dropped the use of the database authentication for a simple htpasswd file though).

Since then, I have also started using [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/). My issue is that not all users on the system should be able to access the different repositories, and the default setup of WebSVN is to allow anyone who can authenticate.

According to the WebSVN documentation, the best way around this is to use subversion's path access system, so I looked to create this, using the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive.

When I do this though, I keep getting "403 Forbidden" messages.

My files look like the following:

I have default policy settings in a file:

```
<Location /svn/>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath  /var/lib/svn/repository

  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Location>
```

Each repository gets a policy file like below:

```
<Location /svn/sysadmin/>
    Include  /var/lib/svn/conf/default_auth.conf
    AuthName "Repository for sysadmin"
    require user joebloggs jimsmith mickmurphy
</Location>
```

The default_auth.conf file contains this:

```
SVNParentPath      /var/lib/svn/repository
AuthType           basic
AuthUserFile       /var/lib/svn/conf/.dav_svn.passwd
AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/lib/svn/conf/svnaccess.conf
```

I am not fully sure why I need the second SVNParentPath in default_auth.conf, but I just added that today as I was getting error messages as a result of adding the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive.

With a totally permissive access file

```
[/]
joebloggs = rw
```

the system worked fine (and was essentially unchanged), but as I soon as I start trying to add any kind of restrictions such as

```
[sysadmin:/]
joebloggs = rw
```

instead, I get the 'Permission denied' errors again. The log file entries are:

```
[Thu May 28 10:40:17 2009] [error] [client 89.100.219.180] Access denied: 'joebloggs' GET websvn:/
[Thu May 28 10:40:20 2009] [error] [client 89.100.219.180] Access denied: 'joebloggs' GET svn:/sysadmin
```

What do I need to do to get this to work? Have configured apache wrong, or is my understanding of the svnaccess.conf file incorrect?

If I am going about this the wrong way, I have no particular attachment to my overall approach, so feel free to offer alternatives as well.

**UPDATE (20090528-1600):**

I attempted to implement [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/13853/how-do-i-restrict-repository-access-via-websvn/13912#13912), but I still cannot get it to work properly.

I know most of the configuration is correct, as I have added

```
[/]
joebloggs = rw
```

at the start and 'joebloggs' then has all the correct access.

When I try to go repository-specific though, doing something like

```
[/]
joebloggs = rw

[sysadmin:/]
mickmurphy = rw
```

then I got a permission denied error for mickmurphy (joebloggs still works), with an error similar to what I already had previously

```
[Thu May 28 10:40:20 2009] [error] [client 89.100.219.180] Access denied: 'mickmurphy' GET svn:/sysadmin
```

Also, I forgot to explain previously that all my repositories are underneath

```
/var/lib/svn/repository
```

**UPDATE (20090529-1245):**

Still no luck getting this to work, but all the signs seem to be pointing to the issue being with path-access control in subversion not working properly. My assumption is that I have not configured apache or svn to properly recognise my repository structure.

This is because the '[/]' entry seems to work perfectly.

It also occurs to me that this is question that may belong better on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate md5 password files using apache's htpasswd utility (located in the bin directory).

Then, in your httpd.conf:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath "repo path"
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Repository"
     AuthUserFile "password file path"
     Require valid-user
     SVNListParentPath on #if you want a repository listing for the whole svn directory
</Location>
```

This will require user authentication, and only username/password combinations located in the password file (from htpasswd) will be accepted for access.

In addition, you can also specify read-only access to everyone, but use the password file for commits, etc by the following (within the location tag):

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
     Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

If I'm understanding what you need, this should solve it for user-level access.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, that if you do use a password file, make sure it is not accessible through the web (ie, no alias or directory are assigned in apache where it is stored).

Comment: I already have a .htpasswd file and that all works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to use subversion's path-based access control, using the svnaccess.conf file that I listed above.

My gut feeling is telling me that this the above configuration is ALMOST correct, and I'm either leaving out an Apache directive, or I am missing something in how I have written out the svnaccess.conf file to get what I need.

Comment: hi @Chris S can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541629/websvn-doesnt-ask-for-authentication-for-using-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

You have to give everybody read access to the root. Afterwards remove read acces from specific repositories as required. Working with user groups might help to keep the configuration small.

You might give it a try like this:

```
[/]
* = r

[sysadmin:/]
mickmurphy =
joebloggs = rw
```