# webSVN doesn't ask for authentication for using a repository

Tags: svn, websvn

I just setup the SVN server on my local network.its working fine as expected but to use SVN more handy way i just configured webSVN. but after configuring webSVN's `config.php` file its shows me all the repositories and its not asking me for any authentication like user name and password. what i have in my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf` is

```
<Location /mysvn>
DAV svn
      SVNParentPath /var/www/html/svn
         AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-acl-conf
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Subversion repos"
         AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
         Require valid-user
         SVNListParentPath on
</Location>
```

I have just uncommented this line in my webvpn's `config.php` file

```
 $config->parentPath('/var/www/html/svn');
```

I am using a single user access control file to manage the permission of different repositories.

if i add following line in my config.php file then the error which i am getting is 'You do not have the necessary permissions to view this content.'

```
$config->useAuthenticationFile('/etc/svn-acl-conf'); // Global access file
```

How do i resolve this permission issue, what configuration i need to do to fix this? give me some hint or idea to solve my issue.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Comment the line useAuthenticationFile and uncomment the next line:

```
$config->addRepository('My Repo', 'http://x.x.x.x/svn/repository', NULL, 'username', 'password');
```

username and password is a svn authentication.

And password protect the main directory by ht-access.

Comment: should i give here a password for specific user ? what i want to do is if i register with particular username then only that user owner repository displayed.

Comment: using this,using this i am able to access all repository on which permission is not given